# How to force an array to display all the values?

Tags: php, arrays, google-analytics-api

the output for my array look similar to this after print_r($segments):

```
Array
(
    [kind] => analytics#segments
    [username] => account@gmail.com
    [totalResults] => 2334
    [startIndex] => 1
    [itemsPerPage] => 1000
    [items] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => -1
                [kind] => analytics#segment
                [selfLink] => https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/segments/gaid::-1
                [segmentId] => gaid::-1
                [name] => All Visits
                [definition] => 
            )
...

        [999] => Array
            (
                [id] => -1
                [kind] => analytics#segment
                [selfLink] => https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/segments/gaid::-1
                [segmentId] => gaid::-1
                [name] => All Visits
                [definition] => 
            )
    )
)
```

This array is an output from google analytics API PHP, the max that it displayed me is ***1000*** rows as mentioned in the ***itemsPerPage*** parameter,  but I do have more than 1000, close to ***2334*** as mentioned in ***totalResults*** parameter.

Does some one have any idea how to force it to display all output at once?

When I run this :

```
 $nextLink = $results->getNextLink()
            ? $results->getNextLink() : 'none';

print($nextLink);
```

The output is a **link**:
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/~all/webproperties/~all/profiles?start-index=1001&max-results=1000

`Accoring to this` [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_analytics_v3_schema_accounts) `I have to use the parameter called` **max-results** `to display more results per page, but I have no idea how to do so, no much documentation about it.`

Any idea how to get the rest of the results using the **max-results** parameter or the **link**?

Comment: This isn't a `print_r` issue - sounds like a Google Analytics API restraint

Comment: Are you **sure** that `count($segments["items"])` returns 2334? I don't think so.

Comment: It is a analytics limit. You need a new request for more results.

Comment: @AaronW. hopefully I will find some work around.

Comment: @AlvinWong, yes 'count($segments["items"])' return 2334

Comment: @GabrielSantos how can I request more results ?

Comment: `max-results=10000` (max allowed is 10.000)  via https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference

Comment: @GabrielSantos better to use the `getNextLink()` and `getPreviousLink()` provided by the API. Same problem will happen if there are 10,001 results.

Comment: @GabrielSantos, Correct->that is how much Google analytics allowed you to retrieve at one call but it's displays it through pagination, I'm looking to display all the results at one page without pagination.

Comment: Google analytics allow only 10.000 rows per request. You need to be creative and use pagination at the backend, storing all rows (doing more than one request) in one array before send to user browser.

Comment: @Chris That is a great idea, can you please explain to me more your example and would you like please to add it to your answer bellow so I could mark it as a correct answer. Thanks a lot! and highly appreciated!

Comment: @mongotop I added pseudo code to demonstrate, can't test it myself and would prefer to not post code I can't test.

Comment: @mongotop If you have some specific code you're trying with this and it's not working, maybe add it as an **Update** section to the question and we'll see what we can do.

Comment: the logic look right! I will test the code and let you know what was the output! Thanks again!!

Comment: I posted some updates, hopefully someone will understand what's going on since there's no much documentation about how to use `max-results` parameter to display more results per page.

Comment: @mongotop Can you post an answer , how you did it.I am on same situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Quick Answer**:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreDevguide#working

Look at the **Pagination Information**, it seems like your data should have a `getNextLink()` and `getPreviousLink()` which may not be part of the data and would not print in a `print_r()`.

When accessing an API through network, and not knowing how much information the API needs to return, you don't want to risk sending larges amount of data all at once.  This could cause a lot of unnecessary traffic and slow the entire system down.

One solution, Pagination, is to send back a set number of responses (1000 in this case) and if the user of the API needs more, have them request the next set explicitly.

**Psuedo Code:**
(Sorry I don't have a working Google-API setup to try this on)

```
$finalArray = array();

//Copy $segments into $finalArray;
while(!empty($segments->getNextLink()))
{
    //Use $segments->getNextLink()
    //$segments now contains the next set of data
    //Copy $segments into $finalArray;
}
```

Comment: I posted the result from your script, I had to hack it little bit so it won't display Errors. but that was the right path to follow! Any idea how to go from there? thanks Chris!